# use dots instead of comma in math mode with babel package use

Tags: punctuation, babel, changes

hi i started to use math mode for lab reports but when i use the babel package (`\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`) the dots changes by comma, i been tried to use `\DeclareMathSymbol` and `\mathcode`.="8000` options but the bug persist. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's not a bug; it's a design choice (motivated by the RAE). Add `\decimalpoint` to the preamble and you will get a dot as decimal separator.